# Why can't I create a file object from a network datastream

Tags: python, networking, https, tar

I'm downloading a tarfile from a REST API, writing it to a local file, then extracting the contents locally. Here's my code:

```
with open ('output.tar.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(o._retrieve_data_stream(p).read())
with open ('output.tar.gz', 'rb') as f:
    t = tarfile.open(fileobj=f)
    t.extractall()
```

`o._retrieve_data_stream(p)` retrieves the datastream for the file.

This code works fine, but it seems unncessarily complicated to me. I think I should be able to read the bytestream directly into the fileobject read by the tarfile. Something like this:

```
with open(o._retrieve_data_stream(p).read(), 'rb') as f:
    t = tarfile.open(fileobj=f)
    t.extractall()
```

I realize that my syntax may be a little shaky there, but I think it communicates what I'm trying to do.

But when I do this, I get an encoding error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 4):

Posting because I solved it while I was writing this. Turns out I needed to use a `BytesIO` object.

This code works as expected:

```
from io import BytesIO

t = tarfile.open(fileobj=BytesIO(o._retrieve_data_stream(p).read()))
t.extractall()
```

Answer (score 0):

Canadian_Marine's answer was very close to what I needed but not *quite* enough for my particular situation. Seeing the BytesIO object inside the `open` command in their answer helped me solve my problem.

I found it necessary to split the request portion out from the `tarfile.open` and then wrap the response content inside a BytesIO object within the `tarfile.open` command. Here is my code:

```
from io import BytesIO
import requests
import tarfile

remote_file=requests.get ('https://download.site.com/files/file.tar.gz')

#Extract tarball contents to memory
tar=tarfile.open(fileobj=BytesIO(remote_file.content))
#Optionally print all folders / files within the tarball
print(tar.getnames())
tar.extractall('/home/users/Documents/target_directory/')
```

This eliminated the `ValueError: embedded null byte` and `expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO` errors that I was experiencing with other methods.